# javascript "window.history.forward(1);" not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, back-button, browser-history

I'm trying to prevent the back button from working on one of my asp.net mvc pages.
   I've read a couple of places that if i put "window.history.forward(1);" in my page it will prevent the back button from working on a given page.
 This is what I did in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.history.forward(1);
        });
    </script>
```

It doesn't seem to be working.  Am I using this incorrectly or is this approach wrong?  thanks.

Comment: You've got an extra `});` in there. That syntax error might be preventing your page from doing anything.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've seen this trick used is to put `history.forward()` on every page before the page where you don't want the back button to work, then every time the user hits the back button it forwards them back to where they were. The common use is to prevent others from returning to a page (usually in a given, linear sequence) once they have progressed. This is sometimes used in the sign-in sequence for banking websites, for example.

As far as I know, there is no way to actually *disable* the back button. Sometimes people get around this by opening the page in a new window, which will not have a history of pages preceding it, and thus nothing to go back to. Others simply display a warning message before going back to inform a user that they may lose unsaved data, if that is the main concern.

That said, maybe this will help you: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

Comment: Good link. Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

maybe:...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function disableBackButton()
   {
     window.history.forward();
   }
   setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
    $(document).ready(function () {
       disableBackButton();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use on the page in which you don't want back button to work.

window.history.forward(1);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant but I found it and it might be worth a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function() {
        null
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this too and no luck. the back button in the browser still works find as well as the back button on my keyboard. hmm, I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me... Hope it helpful for you..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack(){ 
    window.history.forward();
     }
</script>   

 $(document).ready(function() {
            noBack();
});
```

Comment: Hi this is working for me only for one click on browser back button. If I click back button for a second time then it goes to previous page. Please comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
history.go(index)
index =0 //for the current page.
index>0 //e.g 1,2 for forward navigation
index<0 //e.g -1,-2 for backward navigation

history.go(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
```

And in html Body tag write the following code.

```
<body  onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload=" " >
```

Try this, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <script>
            function preventBack() {
                window.history.forward();
            }

            setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);

            window.onunload = function () {
                null
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.history.forward();
function noBack()
{ 
    window.history.forward();
}

function setit() {
    noBack();
}
```

Comment: please can you provide some context around your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
        function preventBack() {
            window.history.forward();
        }

        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);

        window.onunload = function () {
            null
        };
    </script>
```

The code needs to be on the page infront as well as the page you require for it to work